# Why does wepback split my css file into different <style> tags?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, webpack-style-loader

**style.css**

```
/* some styles on this place */
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:100,300,400,700");
```

**vendor.ts**

```
import "./style.css"
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'vendor': './vendor.ts'
    },

    output: {
        path: './dist',
        filename: '[name].js'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, use: ['awesome-typescript-loader'] },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            minimize: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|ico|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: "[name].[ext]",
                            useRelativePath: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },   
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'html-loader',
                        options: {
                            minimize: true,
                            attrs: ['img:src', 'img:data-big', 'link:href']
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }

        ]
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },

    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "index.html" //the simple html template
        }),
        new UglifyJsPlugin(),
    ]
};
```

As output I get the `src/index.html` file with the **two** style tags:

```
<style type="text/css">@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:100,300,400,700);</style>
<style type="text/css"><!-- the remaining part of style.css here --></style>
```

Why does the style-loader apply splitting my css file? This behavior is for **external** url's only (if there is `@import` with some local path it resolves by css-loader)

@guillaume86 on [github](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/44) described this behavior, but without any explanations

webpack 3.x.x

Comment: Just a guess: Did you try setting `minimize` to `false`?

Comment: Looks like it's the default behavior of `style-loader`. You may disable this by adding `singleton: true` to the `options` of `style-loader`.

Comment: @AnDrOiD yep, with the singleton options it surrounds all styles with one style tag as expected. Well, I agree with you it looks like the default behavior of style-loader. But still it's a bit confuse me why is the import module above the remaining part of the style.css whereas
there is vice versa?

Comment: Are you talking about the font you import in your CSS file?

Comment: @AnDrOiD yes, in the style.css the google fonts is **under** the custom styles. But after webpack building it is vice versa (even if singleton  = true)

Comment: Oh, now I understand what you were trying to ask. The reason for this might have something to do with the priority of the external resource, since it takes time to fetch it, I'm not sure though. Why wouldn't you want it at the top?

Comment: @AnDrOiD it's ok for me if an external resource is at the top. Thanks for the help!